# STAG_UNIQ cookie

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, microsoft-edge

Have debian system running apache 2.4.38 and Caucho Resin 4.0.65. Made a simple web page, showing all request data, and observe strange STAG_UNIQ cookie. What program/module is responsible for setting it? Cannot find it either in binaries nor google.

Source code that shows the cookie:

```
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    out.println("\nCookies:");
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (int i = 0; cookies != null && i < cookies.length; i++)
    {
        out.println(cookies[i].getName() + " : " +
            cookies[i].getValue() + " : " +
            cookies[i].getDomain() + " : " +
            cookies[i].getPath() + " : " +
            cookies[i].getMaxAge());
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Response:

```
Cookies:
STAG_UNIQ : aaaDYHhTs_ZyhdYug95ox : null : null : -1
JSESSIONID : aaaCee5N8aEZpeZug95ox : null : null : -1
```

Update: looks like cookie is set by Edge only. Might be an Edge feature?

Comment: Have you looked in the program's source code? Have you asked the maintainers?

Comment: Source is quite clean and simple, it just displays cookies. Will add it right now. Dunno how to ask maintainers and maintainers of what. Looks like it is set by edge only. Still investigating.